# Is it possible to install IDLE on Python 2.5 and Ubuntu

Tags: python-idle, python-2.5

Ubuntu Software Center offers versions of IDLE numbered 2.6 and upwards.  If I have to use Python 2.5 (because of Google App Engine compatibility), will it be possible to still use IDLE?  I am of course assuming that the there is some necessity for the IDLE version number to be the same as the Python version number.

Presently, my invocations of IDLE fail because of _tkinter not being found.  Likewise it is not found when I try to do an import _tkinter interactively.  I then proceeded to install Tcl and Tk and python-tk and one of the IDLE versions being offered (none were labelled 2.5) but _tkinter still does not get imported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem it that tkinter is installed in a different version of Python than IDLE is using.  See this discussion [here](http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/521220-tkinter-module-not-found).

Comment: Drew, you may be right.  On another thread it was said that Ubuntu 10.10 comes with Python 2.6 already installed.  The solution was to install tk-dev before installing Python 2.5.  Then IDLE will work.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4553869/tk-library-and-tcl-library-environment-variables-on-ubuntu